# To do my URL unique

Tags: php, yii

guys! I ask for help.

I have some Controller in my Yii 1. And I need to format URL creation with minimal changes.

Now I have such:

```
<?=Yii::app()->createUrl('/shop-'.$model->id.'-'.$uid.'-'.$model->uid);?>

Web: site.com/shop-200-181-180
```

I need to do my URL unique, to add in this link some changeble variable, that change in each link, for example:
site.com/shop-200-181-180-xxxxxx
xxxxxx - could be number, for example

```
site.com/shop-200-181-180-3977409
site.com/shop-200-181-180-8560291
site.com/shop-200-181-180-5287810
```

and so on

I want to add something like

```
rand(0, 100000)
```

This output:

```
<?=Yii::app()->createUrl('/shop-'.$model->id.'-'.$uid.'-'.$model->uid);?>
```

should remain unchangeble.

My Controller code is:
https://pastebin.com/R3LjeYHz

:(

Help me pls to do this!
I woill be appreciate for help!

Thanks

Comment: Using a random number doesn't guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: I understand this, but random numer is the easiest way to unique it. I have all checkings before. I know php and Yii bad, so it's hadr to me to put this correctly in code.

Comment: "random numer is the easiest way to unique it". A **random** number is NOT unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use current datetime in milliseconds instead of random number.

```
<?=Yii::app()->createUrl('/shop-'.$model->id.'-'.$uid.'-'.$model->uid.'-'.round(microtime(true) * 1000));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use uniqid function of PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

It is not unique 100% but is better option than simple rand

```
<?php
    $sId = uniqid("{$model->id}-{$uid}-", true);
    echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/shop-' . $sId);
?>
```